# How to install an old version of React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to install an old version of React?
Below is a portion of my `package.json` file:

```json
"react": "^18.12.0",
```

Comment: Unfortunately we are still on `18.2.0`. Perhaps in the future :)

Comment: The latest version of React is 18.2.0 now but if you need to install other old versions, You can easily do that using npm,

`npm install react@17.0.0`

after `@`, you can specify the needed version.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using NPM, specify the version by appending a `@` followed by the version:

```
npm install react@18.12.0
```

However, version 18.12.0 does not exist yet: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react?activeTab=versions

Comment: Not exist of this vesrsion (npm install react@18.12.0) , So Please suggest ans fce same erroras given below ; SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token...

Comment: npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.12.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

Comment: **However, version 18.12.0 does not exist yet: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react?activeTab=versions**